# Having trouble populating <asp:DropDownList> with jquery and json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist with a json and jquery. I've got a .json file in a project folder named "scripts" where I've also got all my .js files.
Here it is:

```
{
    Cities: [{
        "City": "Sofia",
        "cityID": "1"
    }, {
        "City": "Plovdiv",
        "cityID": "2"
    }, {
        "City": "Varna",
        "cityID": "3"
    }, {
        "City": "Burgas",
        "cityID": "4"
    },
    {
        "City": "Rousse",
        "cityID": "5"
    },
    {
        "City": "Stara Zagora",
        "cityID": "6"
    },
    {
        "City": "Pleven",
        "cityID": "7"
    },
    {
        "City": "Sliven",
        "cityID": "8"
    },
    {
        "City": "Dobrich",
        "cityID": "9"
    },
    {
        "City": "Shumen",
        "cityID": "10"
    }]
}
```

And here is my js that is on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("Scripts/cities.json", function (obj) {
        $.each(obj.cities, function (key, value) {
            $("#db_City").append("<option>" + value.City + "</option>");
                });
        });
```

I can't figure out why its not populating, I can't tell what I'm missing since I'm a complete novice at this. Thank you for any tips/advice that I get in advance.

Comment: As far as JavaScript and jQuery are concerned, there's no such thing as an `asp:DropDownList`. It's just normal HTML. So look at the actual HTML in your browser. And make sure your ID's are matching up. Look for errors in your JavaScript console as well. Also, if you're learning ASP.NET for the first time, why are you wasting time with Web Forms? That framework is dying. Learn [MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- in Scripts/cities.json you have Cities: change to "Cities"
- in the each loop you have obj.cities: change to obj.Cities

In any case you can declare your json as a library and include it like a normal js. It's enough to associate  the object to a variable.

The snippet:

```js
var obj = {
    Cities: [{
        "City": "Sofia",
        "cityID": "1"
    }, {
        "City": "Plovdiv",
        "cityID": "2"
    }, {
        "City": "Varna",
        "cityID": "3"
    }, {
        "City": "Burgas",
        "cityID": "4"
    },
        {
            "City": "Rousse",
            "cityID": "5"
        },
        {
            "City": "Stara Zagora",
            "cityID": "6"
        },
        {
            "City": "Pleven",
            "cityID": "7"
        },
        {
            "City": "Sliven",
            "cityID": "8"
        },
        {
            "City": "Dobrich",
            "cityID": "9"
        },
        {
            "City": "Shumen",
            "cityID": "10"
        }]
};


//$.getJSON("..../data.json", function (obj) {
    $.each(obj.Cities, function (key, value) {
        $("#db_City").append("<option>" + value.City + "</option>");
    });
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="db_City"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you, fixing the 2 issues made the drodownlist work perfectly.

Comment: :) glad to help you